# How can I get a list of Git branches that I've recently checked out?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

When moving between Git branches I sometimes forget the name of a branch I was recently on. How can I display a list of recently checked out branches/tags/commits **in order of checkout**?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

#### Summary:

You can use Git's `reflog` to show recent movements **in order of checkout**: `git reflog`

#### Script:

Here's a script you can download and use via `git recent` from inside any Git repository: https://gist.github.com/jordan-brough/48e2803c0ffa6dc2e0bd

#### Usage:

```sh
$ (master) git recent -n 5

1) master  4) deleted-branch
2) stable  5) improve-everything
3) fun
Choose a branch: 2

$ (stable) …
```

See [the gist](https://gist.github.com/jordan-brough/48e2803c0ffa6dc2e0bd) for more details/options.

#### Details:

Here's essentially what the script does to make the reflog output more usable:

```
$ git reflog | egrep -io "moving from ([^[:space:]]+)" | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | head -n5
master
stable
fix-stuff
some-cool-feature
feature/improve-everything
```

Comment: Using the gist by Jordan as a base, I made a script to checkout a recent branch by selecting it from the list: https://gist.github.com/fritz-c/c1e528b09bc1c0827a3c

Comment: Thanks @Chris! I've updated my script to incorporate that idea and I've listed you as a contributor in the script.

Comment: Updated script is this, btw: https://gist.github.com/jordan-brough/48e2803c0ffa6dc2e0bd

Comment: Can you incorporate this answer in a git alias? I do not know how to use grep and other cli tools in gitconfig alias. Preferably with the option -<n> like git log?

Comment: @kuga the gist has instructions on how to make it available like `git recent` (download the script, make it executable, put it in your path).  Is there a reason you want to use a git alias instead?

Comment: No specific reason. Its just easier. Did not think of making it a script though :)

Comment: `egrep` can be skipped by using: `git reflog --grep-reflog='^checkout: moving from [^ ]\{1,\}'` (explation for `\{1,\}` instead of `+` at https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar one liner in my zshell , it takes an arg to specify how long the history should be, which defaults to 10.

```
alias bstack='f() { git reflog | grep checkout | cut -d " " -f 8 | uniq | head ${1} | cat -n };f'
```

for example, to list the last 3 branches

```
bstack -3


 1  my-current-branch
 2  my-previous-branch
 3  my-third-most-recent-branch
```

I derived a couple useful shortcuts from this

```
alias bjmp='fn() { bstack ${1} | tail -1 | cut -f 2 | xargs git checkout  }; fn'
```

allows me to specify from the numbers above which branch to check out

```
bjmp -3
```

will checkout "my-third-most-recent-branch"

```
alias b="bstack -1"
alias bpop="bjmp -2"
```

are also useful to see the current branch in a single keystroke (although this is not the easiest way to do this), and to just checkout the previous branch.

Comment: +1 For providing a solution that does not require a script, and suggesting a usefull alias for the command.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I would recommend changing `grep checkout` to `grep checkout:` because the word `checkout` occurs during rebases as well, which results in an empty line when running this script.  The `:` only seems to appear with normal checkouts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a powershell script I cobbled together based on the other answers here:

```
function gsh() {
  # git switch with history of recent branches
  $branch = & git reflog | Select-String -Pattern "moving from (\S+) to (\S+)" | %{ $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value } | Invoke-Fzf -NoSort
  if ($branch)
  {
    & git switch $branch
  }
}
```

It makes use of the awesome fzf fuzzy finder to allow interactive selection of the branch to switch to - including fuzzy-filtering of the branches! See [PSFzf](https://github.com/kelleyma49/PSFzf) for details on how to get the `Invoke-Fzf` command.