# How to sort the output of git branch by most recent checkout

Tags: git, branch

I have a lot of local branches.  Running `git branch` lists them and they overflow the page.  I often want to toggle between the currently checked out branch and the branch I was working on last, or possibly one before the last.  The process is to scan the list of 20-30 local branches by eye or possibly command+f if I'm lucky enough to remember a keyword (or ticket number).

Instead I'd like to say `git branch` and have it display branches by checkout order.  The same way you seem many items listed in many programs ordered by most recent activity.  This seems like an obvious default choice for order criterion and I'm surprised it isn't git's default.

## edit:

i revised my question to ask only about a sort by checkout.  i'm unable to find a sorting predicate that will filter the output of `git branch` by the date of each branches most recent checkout.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether this is what you want: `git reflog --pretty="%D" | grep -v ^$` (I'm sure there's a better way to do this).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of git branches, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit)

Comment: Most recent commit and most recent checkout are two very different metrics.

Comment: @jthill thats why i edited my questions to be about which one i care about.  am i missing something

Comment: ? No, was addressing phd's comment, your question is clearly not a dup of that.  `@{-1}` is git syntax for the previous explicit checkout, @{-2} for the one before that.  You don't need to generate a list and pick from it, just say what you want directly.

Comment: @musicmatze one improvement - `git reflog --pretty="%D" | grep -v ^$ | uniq`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a list of Git branches that I've recently checked out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095061/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-that-ive-recently-checked-out)

Answer (score 4):

List Branches in the order they were checked out (not in last commit order):

```
git log -g --grep-reflog "checkout:" --format="%gs" | cat -n | sed -E "s/^\s+([0-9]+).*from (.*) to .*/\1 \2/g" | tac
```

You can then check one of them out with

```
git checkout @{-nnn}
```

where `nnn` is the number displayed before the branch name. To toggle between the current and previous branch, simply use

```
git checkout -
```

You can combine above command to new git command like this:

```
git config --global alias.lb '!git log -g --grep-reflog "checkout:" --format="%gs" | cat -n | sed -E "s/^\s+([0-9]+).*from (.*) to .*/\1 \2/g" | tac; read -p "Aussuchen: " i; git checkout @{-$i}'
```

to use

```
git lb
```

to display the last used branches and select one of them.

Comment: Note: some environments, like macOS, don't have `tac`. So use `| tail -r` instead. Or more usefully, add `alias tac='tail -r'` to the rc/profile file for your shell. I also had trouble with the sed operation, so here was my final command to get the last 25 on macOS: `git log -25 -g --grep-reflog "checkout:" --format="%gs" | sed -E "s/^checkout: moving from (.*) to.*/\1/g" | cat -n | tail -r`

Comment: to this i would add `| sort | head -n 5` to show only last 5 branches and in order of recency

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the  for-each-ref option?  There are a lot of sortable fields.

Here is one that sorts by authordate

```
 git for-each-ref  --sort='-*authordate'
```

When I test this on my own smaller set of branches, the most recently created/checked out one is at the top.

It looks like these are the only DATE/TIME fields in the git-ref structure:

```
"authordate"
"committerdate"
"taggerdate"
"creatordate"
```

You can find out more here by trying this command to get the docs:

```
git for-each-ref --help
```

Maybe as script that checks  .git/refs/heads for updates?

Comment: thanks.  but i don't see any that go by checkout date.  its probably a coincidence that most recently checked out and most recently committed-to happen to coincide with each other.  in my case, as someone who frequently checks out various branches without committing any work, that coincidence rarely arises.

Comment: @AlexBollbach  I guess that's one of the dates that git-ref does not have/support.  I updated the answer with the only 4 that looks like date/time fields.  So it looks like you can order on the one's you've committed too but, aside from some tricky directory timestamp checks with a batch script of some type, ordering by checkout date itself doesn't seem to be native to git. :/     The test cases I have available to myself were not complex/large enough to expose the defect in the suggested answer.

Comment: sure i'm sure a sufficiently bashful programmer could conjure up something to do this non natively.

Answer (score 1):

> I often want to toggle between the currently checked out branch and the branch I was working on last, or possibly one before the last.

Thank you for describing the situation giving you difficulties, as well as asking how to implement the solution you're attempting.

Git's got a very direct way of dealing with this.  To repeat the checkout you were working on last,

```
git checkout @{-1}
```

and to repeat the one before last

```
git checkout @{-2}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-1}` to get the names, `git show @{-1}` to get the commit details