# In Git how can I cycle through previously checked out branches?

Tags: git, branch

I know git checkout - goes back to the last branch I checked out.

Is there a simple way to list the last n branches I checked out then index check out one of them?

I’m not looking for external solutions involving tools like bash or grep.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095061/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-that-ive-recently-checked-out Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+checked+out+branches