# How can I get a list of Mercurial (hg) bookmarks, ordered by most recently used?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

I want to get a list of all the bookmarks in a Mercurial repository with the "freshest" bookmarks at the top, where the "freshest" bookmark is the one that I've `hg update`'d to most recently (and is, therefore, more likely to be one I want to pay attention to).

Is there a way I can use Mercurial to either (a) sort the list of bookmarks by latest commit, or (b) get a list of bookmarks together with each one's last-commit date, in some kind of machine-readable format?

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit) offers an excellent way to do this with Git, but doesn't help me for Mercurial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow may not know yet, but sure does the integrated mercurial help, especially if you ask it about revsets `hg help revsets`. Then it's a piece of cake to try

```
hg log -r "sort(bookmark())"
```

If you need anything else than standard output ask mercurial help on templating (`hg help templates`). E.g. try

```
hg log -r "sort(bookmark())" -T "{bookmark} {node|short} {date|isodate} {author}:\n{desc|firstline}"
```