# Get the id of the last git commit on any branch

Tags: git

I'm currently using `git rev-parse origin/master` to retrieve the id of the last commit on master branch. But I would like to get the very last commit on any branch of the project. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you.
**EDIT:** I found the way of retrieving the last commits IDs:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(objectname)'
```

But I would like to retrieve only the very last ID instead of the whole list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of git branches, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just had a look at it. They look alike but I only need the id, not the other information. I'll edit the post if I manage to do it using `git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/` as the answers of the post suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I finally did it.

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(objectname)' --count=1
```

The output is the sha of the very last commit on any branch of the project.