# How can I view branches in Azure Repos without the tree view?

Tags: git, azure, azure-repos

The documentation [Manage branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-your-branches?view=azure-devops) says that branches are listed with a collapsable tree view when you're viewing them in Azure.

> If your team uses a forward slash separator in your branch names,
>   you'll see a collapsible tree view for those branches.

[image: Screenshot from documentation]

I find the collapsible tree view a distraction when I'm just trying to find the most recent branch.

How can I view them without the collapsible tree view in Azure Repos, or failing that, is there a way to expand all folders at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any obvious way to configure the branch representation on Azure side.

That leaves you with a local command-line alternative to [find the most recent branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188364/6309)

```
git fetch
git branch -av --sort=committerdate | head 1
```